# How to Implement the folders browsing using two Fragments in a activity?

Tags: android, file, android-fragments, fragment, directory

I am working in Android. My intention is to take 2 fragment containers like leftfragment and rightfragment in a main Fragment. And in left Fragment I will load folders and files. If I click on folder Item the right Fragment has to load the list of clicked folder items. I have done fine up to here.

Now when I am clicking on right fragment folder Item the current fragment should appear in Leftfragment without losing its state and the new items from the clicked folder has to appear at rightfragment. and again same like rightfragment to left and new content has to appear in rightfragment.

The main Fragment has the following layout.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a temporary fragment in between to hold the right fragment while you replace it with the new detailed one. then you can replace the left fragment with the temporary fragment where you stored the right fragment.

Comment: Thank you but can you explain in detail and share if any sample code if any.

Comment: you can use something like tempFragment = rightFragment; getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.right_container, newFragment).commit(); getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.left_container, tempFragment).commit(); Please accept the answer if you find it useful :)